# Save the current device location in one variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, geolocation, device

I want to save the devices current location into one variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Post your code...Let's see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the geolocation APIs to get the current location.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/html5-geolocation/

save location in a variable using the API i have mentioned above as:

```
var currentLocation; //this variable will store current location.
     jQuery(window).ready(function(){  
                jQuery("#btnInit").click(initiate_geolocation);  
            });  
            function initiate_geolocation() {  
              //store current location
              currentLocation =  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query);  
            }  
            function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
                alert('Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' ' +  
                      'Lon: ' + position.coords.longitude);  
            }
```